# How to show that $\int_{0}^{1}\left({x^u\over \ln(x)}+{x^v\over 1-x}\right)\mathrm dx=\gamma-H_v+\ln(u+1)?$

Tags: integration

[It is well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876524/whats-the-behaviour-of-i-n-int-01-left-frac1-log-x-frac11-x-rightndx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left({1\over \ln(x)}+{1\over 1-x}\right)\mathrm dx=\gamma\tag1$$

Messing around with $(1)$ using wolfram integrator, we have

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left({x^u\over \ln(x)}+{x^v\over 1-x}\right)\mathrm dx=F(u,v)\tag2$$

$H_0=0.$

**How do we show that $F(u,v)=\gamma-H_v+\ln(u+1)?$**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use 
\begin{eqnarray*}
H_v= \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^v}{1-x} dx
\end{eqnarray*}
and 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^u-1}{\ln x} = \int_0^u  x^t dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 ( \frac{x^u}{\ln x}+ \frac{x^v}{1-x}) dx &=& \int_0^1 ( \frac{1}{\ln x}+ \frac{1}{1-x}- \frac{1-x^v}{1-x}+\frac{x^u-1}{\ln x}) dx
\end{eqnarray*}
The first two terms of the RHS give $ \gamma $ , the third term gives $H_v$ and the fourth term is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^u-1}{\ln x} dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^u  x^t dt dx = \int_0^u \int_0^1   x^t dx dt = \int_0^u \frac{1}{1+t}  dt = \ln (1+u).
\end{eqnarray*}